# Use Flow and Action (Create a Record) to Conditionally Create Opportunity From Account

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, action

**Scenario** - I currently have an Action that can be clicked on the Account page to create a pre-populated Opportunity.  Now I want to use Flow (specifically a decision), to build a Flow Button (Button that executes a Flow) that only allows for the execution of the Action if the Account Status is set to Active.  The following image shows what I have so far (the Action is the Action mentioned above):

[image]

**Questions**

1. Bigger - How can I use a Flow to fulfill the scenario?
2. Smaller -How can I bring the AccountId into the flow from the Account where the button was clicked (i.e. bring contextual information into the Flow's scope)?

Answer (score 1):

- Object-based actions of type Flow will pass the ID into a flow variable that must be named recordId
- Flow should do a Get Records using recordId as key into a record variable
- Decision block to inspect Account Status and route to your sub flow.